# PyObjC: how to create a simple dummy app without nib-file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pyobjc, objective-c-runtime

For various reasons, I cannot/want not use a NIB-file (or any other external resources).

How can I create a simple dummy app (e.g. some simple menu, some empty window) with PyObjC, i.e. with pure Python code?

Comment: You've looked through all the [sample code](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/examples/) in the PyObjC docs? Many of them don't use nibs.

Comment: @Josh: Yes. Which one? I haven't found any which doesn't.

Comment: @Josh: Or even if they don't use nibs, they don't come as pure Python code.

Comment: Hmm, my mistake. I could've sworn there were at least a handful. What do you mean by "pure Python code", though? If you're calling into the Cocoa frameworks from Python, you're going to have to get used to the weird renamed Obj-C methods. No way around that, I'm afraid; that's just how the bridge works.

Comment: "pure Python" = `$ python myscript.py` and only modules which are preinstalled (i.e. of course including `objc` etc.). Of course I know that I need to use the Obj-C bridge (i.e. PyObjC).

Comment: @Albert are you still interested on this question ?

Comment: @mmgp: Yes, although I have already found some useful resources. I just forgot to put it here. Doing that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very helpful introduction with sample code was the [Introduction to PyObjC and Cocoa on lethain.com](http://lethain.com/an-epic-introduction-to-pyobjc-and-cocoa/) with some sample code [here](https://github.com/lethain/metawindow/blob/master/MWController.py) (and related files).

I also have an own project now (a [music player](http://albertz.github.com/music-player/)) where I construct the whole Cocoa GUI dynamically. The main code of that part is [here](https://github.com/albertz/music-player/blob/master/guiCocoa.py).

Comment: I don't think `MainMenu.xib` and other related files were created purely with Python, were they (considering your own project) ?

Comment: @mmgp: No, just look at it. But you are right, the examples at my first link don't fully create all the GUI elements dynamically in Python.